# DBeaver - Column "columns name' is read-only: No corresponding table column

Tags: dbeaver

I am using DBeaver on Mac and suddenly can't edit/udpate anything on results cell, I get this message:

> Column "columns name' is read-only: No corresponding table column.

However, when I use UPDATE command it works just fine.

The challenge is that I have multiple updates to make and it is very convenient to do it ib the results cells.

Other users still can do it and I am suspecting this is something related to my DBeaver client

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: 7 answers that are not answers and 0 comments. Incredible.

Answer (score 47):

I have faced the same issue, when added a column from script and tried to update data on table from UI. it can solved by disconnecting and connecting to  database as DBeaver currently don't refresh the DDLs.

Answer (score 12):

Incase you created a new table and the cells won't update, DBeaver didn't probably refresh the table you created. In that case all you have to do is click refresh option in sidemenu

Comment: This worked for me, DBeaver 22.1.0 linux

Answer (score 6):

As SKIFO mentioned, refreshing the table works. You can do it from the left menu.

[image: dbeaver screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, solved after ommiting rowid as column in then select clause. It appears to be a conflict betwween named an * as column selector in 22.3.3 version. Try to use only * or name explicitly selected columns.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your feedback and suggestions. Unfortunately, Nothing has worked from the suggested solutions or it was a way too much work to fix this issue.

I downgraded to Version 22.2.2 and everything works perfectly again.

Thank again!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using mysql in Dbeaver. I had to check the below two configurations

1. Read table metadata (unique keys)
2. Read table references (foreign keys)

[image]

Comment: I already have these checked. Somehow it seems me trying to run an invalid MySQL query (putting a SELECT inside of an INSERT in an intuitive but incorrect way) set the columns for the table to read-only, and then caused a Java crash. Refreshing hasn't helped, restarting hasn't, and I already have those checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 1):

This is really dumb. I fixed it by deleting comment from script body

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me too. If the SQL query contains comments the table editor gets locked for some reason. After removing the inline comments of the query the table editor was not locked.
E.g.: `SELECT * FROM table #mycomment` does not work

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue, what fixed it for me was refreshing the table in the database navigator, really weird though, before the last update I never encountered this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a comment (with a `#` not `--`) right above the query. For some weird reason(maybe there's an explanation idk), when I insert an empty line between the comment and my `SELECT` query it doesn't give me this message and allows me to make edits in the binary editor.

NOTE: Based on observation in my intel mac, with DBeaver `Version 23.1.5.`

Looks like this is reported on github: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/18851#issuecomment-1408289013

edit1: Add Github link

edit2: clarify comment message type

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. Update to version 23.0.1 helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had to expand the columns of the affected table and then refresh while right clicking one of the columns.  Just right clicking and refreshing the left side wasn't sufficient.  DBeaver 22.3.2 Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the DBeaver and restart it. Hope it will fix this

Answer (score 0):

Just head over to **Database Navigator** in the left pane.

Click on the **connection** the table that you've altered is associated with.

Navigate to **Databases > your-database-name > Schemas > public > Tables**

**Right click** the table and hit **Refresh**.

Now, re-run the select query.

This solved the problem for me.

**PS**: If, this didn't work for you, try refreshing the specific **column** that you've made changes to.

Answer (score 0):

On version 24.0.0.202403091004
If I paste a qry and run it, the columns are in read only.
If I then click on the table name and click ctrl+space dbeaver recognize the table and then columns are not read only any more and I can edit the value directly in the qry result.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. But I figured there is a space behind the string...!Check your strings!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35844523)